# FullCalendar.io not displaying events fed from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have tried numerous ways to feed the `events` of the calendar. I have tried putting the JSON data into a variable and doing `events = result` and I have tried AJAX like I have now. The data is being fetched from a php function and it is the right syntax, i console log the data and here is what is returned: `{title: 1, start: "2020-07-23"}`. So I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:
      {
        url: '/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function() {
          alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
      }
    });
```

Ajax Handler:

```
elseif($_POST['action'] == 'getPeopleCountOnDate') {
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $count = getPeopleCountOnDate($connection, $date);
        echo $count;
      }
```

PHP Script

```
function getBookingEventInfo($connection) {
  $dates;

  $query = "SELECT reservation_date, count(*) FROM bookings GROUP BY reservation_date";
  if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($date, $count);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      $dates = array(
        "title" => $count,
        "start" => formatDate($date, 14)
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
  return json_encode($dates);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `response` contains only `{title: 1, start: "2020-07-23"}` as you've mentioned in the question then you have a problem because it's not an array.

FullCalendar requires an array of events, not a single object. Even if that array will only contain 1 event, it must still be an array. Your server would need to return `[{title: 1, start: "2020-07-23"}]` as the JSON in order for it to work.

To achieve that in your PHP code you can write it like this:

```
function getBookingEventInfo($connection) {
  $dates = array(); //declare an array to contain all the results
  $query = "SELECT reservation_date, count(*) FROM bookings GROUP BY reservation_date";

  if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($date, $count);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      //push the query result into the main array
      $dates[] = array(
        "title" => $count,
        "start" => formatDate($date, 14)
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
  return json_encode($dates);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to wrap the ajax code in `[]` so it is `events: [{...........}]` would this not be a test to that ? It's worth mentioning though when I do wrap it in the square brackets I get the error of `Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined`

Comment: `events: [{...........}]` won't work - with that you're wrapping the events option in the calendar config, not the actual event data. Your **server** needs to return an array as the response to the AJAX call.  Right now it's returning `{title: 1, start: "2020-07-23"}` and it needs to return `[{title: 1, start: "2020-07-23"}]`. What I mean is: you need to modify your ajax_handler.php code. If you need help with doing that, please post that PHP script in your question.

Comment: Thanks. See my updated answer. You were only encoding just a single query result. So even if your query returned many rows you'd only ever have seen one of them in the JSON. I've amended it so it creates a main array and then pushes each result into that array.

Comment: You are a gorgeous person! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

**Update 2**: Just in case, I would delete the success callback, maybe it is preventing your calendar component to get the data because it may be a sort of interceptor.

Update: I think the event you are returning in json may not be in the right format. In [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/event-object) they say *start* should be a complete timestamp. I think YYYY-MM-DD may not be enough, but add also the missing parts (ex: 2009-11-05T13:15:30Z)

---

Did you read [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/events-json-feed)?

One think that is obscure in your answer is, what did you pass as **data**?
And look at the docs, they use eventSources as an array.

Comment: I have read the docs of course before coming here, and yes I have also tried wrapping my code in `[ ]` but then i get en error `Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined`

Comment: You didn't answer: what is inside *data*? Show us that part.

Comment: `var data = {action: 'getBookingEventInfo'}` This is just for the php function which returns the json. Like I said, the JSON gets returned with no issue

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Comment: Despite the JSON being returned correctly, it's not filling `events`

Comment: I thought this too, if I enter manually the same JSON object that is returned, it works, so I don't think the JSON format is the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217978/discussion-between-codigo-morsa-and-tierno).

Comment: _"I think YYYY-MM-DD may not be enough"_ ...no that's no true. fullCalendar will accept a date without a time - it treats them as all-day events when it finds no time attached. _"what did you pass as data"_ ... how is that relevant? The only relevant thing is the content of the response. And deleting the success callback will have no effect - jQuery's $.ajax can have (multiple) promise-based callback handlers attached to it as well as that (which is what fullCalendar does), and all of them will execute when a successful response is received.